# EF Core SaveChangesAsync is slow when many items are tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have a Grid control (WinForms) that is used for viewing/updating data but executing `SaveChangesAsync()` is very slow (3 seconds) for updating one object. I'm finding it difficult to solve this performance issue while also sticking with DDD.

One might suggest using a CRUD approach instead of DDD, but this is only a part of the application. Would I want to use CRUD for this view, if I use DDD in other parts of the app? Seems like it would break encapsulation and confuse other developers on the project. If I did this, would I put them in separate bounded contexts?

Another option is to enable `AsNoTracking*()`. The problem is that my aggregate is `Product` and the entity is `ProductRecipe` (the parts needed to make the product). I only need to track `ProductRecipe` entities, but since `ProductRecipe`s are accessed via the aggregate `Product`, I need to track them the same.

My final option is to just make `ProductRecipe` an aggregate which would allow me to query it separately from `Product`.

What's the best way to fix this performance issue?

Details:
EF Core 5
WinForms

Comment: The challenge for thick client applications is managing the lifetime scope of the DbContext. The longer a DbContext is open, the more entities it is tracking so the slower read and write operations become over time. The DbContext should ideally be scoped to live no longer than a view visit, ideally where certain operations like a Save or Refresh, or changing a parent row recycle the DbContext to release all tracked references and refresh potentially stale data. You will likely need to include code for affected forms to show how the Context is being initialized and used.

Comment: I have a repository layer and it creates a fresh instance of DbContext. I've also confirmed this in the Change Tracker. All the bloat comes from a single call.

Comment: Have you hooked up a profiler to the database to inspect what queries are being run during the operation? It's impossible to spot potential "gotchas" without seeing actual code. How many entities are expected to be changed when an item is saved? Are you relying on change tracking or doing something like a `Update` for several entities?